# How to define in swift an optional variable for a function type, which can be nil?

Tags: swift

I would like to have a variable to hold a function, but which is initialized to nil. I'm trying to make it an optional, but I get an error.

```
var OnClick: (UIButton!) -> ()? = nil
```

I get this error

```
Could not find an overload for '__conversion' that accepts the supplied arguments
```

If I remove the ?, I also get the same error.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You just have to wrap it in parentheses:

```
var OnClick: ((UIButton!) -> ())? = nil
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Cezary's correct answer here. If someone need in detail explanation. Here you go.

### Explaination

```
var OnClick: (UIButton!) -> ()?
```

defines a variable named OnClick which stores a function type. The function accepts a `Implicitly Unwrapped Optional` and return optional `Void`. Note that optional is not the function itself but return type of the function. So you can't assign nil.

```
var OnClick: ((UIButton!) -> ())?
```

defines a variable named OnClick which stores a `optional function`. The function is such that accepts `Implicitly Unwrapped Optional` and return `Void`.